# Accessing HTML attributes in Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

Here is the code I'm using:

```
location = block.xpath("*/img")
puts location
```

And this outputs:

```
<img src="/images/p.gif" height="1" width="0">
```

What I want to do is get the width attribute out of the html, but I can't seem to get that too work. I think I need to put `['width']` somewhere in my code, and I've tried following various examples online but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the xpath syntax from this [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/).

Try `block.at_xpath("*/img")["width"]`, or `*/img/@width` if there is just one  element.

Comment: I guess you mean `*/img/@width`.

Comment: @Micheal, yeah with that small edit it worked great. I think he has an extra paren too in the first example.

Comment: `block.xpath` returns a NodeSet of elements. You want `block.at_xpath` to return a single element. Also, note that using `*/img/@width` will give you the Attribute object, but you want to put a `.text` or `.value` or `.content` on there to get the value of the attribute out as a string.

Answer (score 13):

CSS selectors tend to be easier and more readable:

```
puts block.at('img')[:height]
```

Comment: Or `block.at_css('img')[:height]` or just `block.at('img')[:height]`.

Comment: Yes! I couldn't remember what that method was called. Post updated.